# Salesforce DX and Profile settings?

Tags: profile

I have a weird issue I’m having with Salesforce DX. We’re looking to convert to unlocked packages. When I install an unlocked package, I can see the metadata flagged as being a part of the package for things like objects and layouts and even custom labels.

But I am having an issue with profiles. I try to include non standard profiles in the package and install it but does not show up in the scratch .org I install to. I even tried source:push to the scratch .org and install the package but still not showing up as managed.

Is there a step I’m missing with profiles or are they not compatible?